# Matlab Error- fplot();

Tags: matlab, plot

```
>> fplot(fh,[-2 4])
??? Undefined function or variable "e".

Error in ==> myfun at 3
Y(:,2) = e(:).^x;
Error in ==> fplot at 102
x = xmin; y = feval(fun,x,args{4:end});
```

I tried to plot two function using this m file.

```
function Y = myfun(x)
Y(:,1) = 3*x;
Y(:,2) = e(:).^x;
```

Comment: You appear to be using the vector `e(:)` without actually defining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Donnie mentioned in their comment, the variable `e` is undefined in your m-file.

If you have defined `e` elsewhere, you have to pass it to `myfun` so that the function knows its value. Since `fplot` does not accept plotting functions with more than one input value, you need to pass it an anonymous function.

First, you need to change the definition of `myfun` to include `e` as input:

```
function Y = myfun(x,e)
Y(:,1) = 3*x;
Y(:,2) = e(:).^x;
```

Then, you create your function handle fh like this (fh still only takes one input, Matlab uses the value of `e` as it was defined in the workspace at the time you create the function handle):

```
fh = @(x)(myfun(x,e))
```

Finally, you can call fplot like you used to

```
fplot(fh,[-2 4])
```

Comment: problem solved . But Can some one tell how to get root visually on the graph.?

Comment: In the figure window, click on the data cursor and read the x-value of the root from the datatip, as demonstrated here: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f4-44221.html